# Deleting some cells in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 30,000 contacts on my excel sheet and some have not included their emails. I am a beginner at excel, and would like to know how to delete all cells without emails as well as the corresponding names (in another column) without ruining the order of both columns. For example, I want to get rid of |John Smith||no email|. Sorry if I am not being very clear...

Comment: This isn't very clear, which is why you've received the downvotes. Do you want to remove those rows completely and shift everything up? Or leave blank rows? Additionally, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way is to add a filter to the top-most row of your data, then for the email column, set it so only "blanks" is selected. This will temporarily hide all of the other rows and only display the ones with a missing email address. You can now just highlight them all and delete. Once they are gone, remove the filter and the rest of your data will reappear.

Comment: Depending on what the email column may or may not contain, filtering on *Text Filters, Does not contain @* might be a better option.